# Can XGBoost learn more complicated interactions/features?

Tags: interaction, boosting, feature-engineering, gradient

For a set of features {a, b, c, d . . . n}, XGBoost can easily learn, say, a*d. In practice can it also effectively learn a/c? Or (a + b + c + 2)/d? Or (c^(2*d))/*(b^a)? I'd imagine some of this depends on the amount of data available and the hyperparameters, but I am wondering about general guidelines.

Comment: why not try this out yourself? Generate some data from $y=a/c + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is normally distributed, then fit XGBoost to those data and see how it does.

Comment: I agree with the comment above: try a simulation, make sure to simulate both a training and a test set, and see how your model performs on the test set. Since you control the simulation (and specifically the std deviation of the epsilon noise term), you know the minimum achievable test set rmse that would be achieved by an optimal model that knew the true regression function.

Comment: @Adrian I'm moreso wondering what is theoretically possible in general

Comment: Yes, it is theoretically possible (+1) but a lot will depend on the data at hand. Please my answer below for more details (and a simulation).

Answer (score 8):

You are correct. This strongly depends on the amount of data and the nature of the data too.

The functional form of $y = a/c + \epsilon$ can actually be quite tricky and in the case of a booster, we might severely overfit our training set. That division is a killer in cases where $a$ and $c$ are of different signs, if the sign is the same then the situation is much easier. Ultimately, boosting is performing a recursive partitioning of our sample space (through piece-wise flat functions), which means that even a seemingly trivial $y = x$ relation will need quite a few leaves to give us the perfect result a simple linear regression could do "immediately". That said, gradient boosters can be seen as "universal function approximators" as their building blocks (binary trees) are universal function approximators themselves; please see my answer to the question: *[XGBoost: universal approximator?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/614244/xgboost-universal-approximator)* for more details.

With that in mind, it is good practice to use a baseline model to check if we are getting genuine improvements or not. I made a little toy simulation myself below and we can see that the impact of the `easy` indicator is massive. In the `easy=True` case where our covariates come from $N(10,1)$ so sign reversals are rare our booster generalises fine, if our covariates come from $N(0,1)$ (i.e. `easy=False`) the test performance is horrible, despite potentially a strong in-sample performance. On the other hand, a simple ridge regression performs much more consistently (bad or good).

```
import numpy as np 
from xgboost import XGBRegressor 
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error, r2_score
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
  
N, p = 2000, 3
seed = 2023
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
easy = False

X = rng.normal(10 if easy else 0, 1, [N, p])
y = X[:,0] / X[:,1] + X[:,2]
X_train, X_test,  y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=seed)

booster = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=200, learning_rate=0.02)
booster = booster.fit(X_train, y_train)

ridge =  RidgeCV()
ridge.fit(X_train, y_train) 
 
def results(desc, y_true, y_pred):
    print(f"{desc} has " +
          f"RMSE of {np.round(mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred, squared=False),3)}, " +
          f"MAE of {np.round(mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred),3)}, " +
          f"R2 of {np.round(r2_score(y_true, y_pred),3)}.")

results("Ridge Regression on test-set", y_test, ridge.predict(X_test))
results("Ridge Regression on train-set", y_train, ridge.predict(X_train))   

results("XGBoost Regression on test-set", y_test, booster.predict(X_test))
results("XGBoost Regression on train-set", y_train, booster.predict(X_train)) 


from watermark import watermark
print(watermark(packages="numpy,xgboost,sklearn"))
# numpy  : 1.23.5
# xgboost: 1.7.6
# sklearn: 1.2.2
```